# Indexing for first name and last name

Tags: database, database-design, indexing

What is the best approach to index first name and last name of a person? Lets assume that users can search  first name, last name and both of them together.

- Should I have to create multiple column index or separate indexes?
- Should I have to use index prefixes?

Also we can assume that people are from different nations. Would using prefixes be unnecessary in that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Situation is just clear.

Create index on surname, and optionally add first name to the same index on second position.

This is the result of frequent used business rule, that searching is done by surname.
Surname is the most selective, and any searching form bases on surname. (of course if you are not designing application for Icelandic company).

Adding first name is optional, and depends on size of table

Comment: It is a good tip about business rule but Shark's answer is more satisfactory for me.

Comment: Is an index on surnames only not slow because it has to handle many duplicates ?

Answer (score 3):

- You should create a First Name/Last Name multi-column index.
- You should create a Last Name/First Name multi-column index.

Note that inserts and update will be slower (you don't get something for nothing).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question correctly, but your best bet would be to create a nonclustered index on the most queried fields.  For instance, you can create a nonclustered index on firstname and lastname.  You should see performance gains through that.